# How to use JAXB in Liferay , Getting ClassCastException

Tags: xml, jaxb, liferay, classcastexception

I have created AddSystem.java and ObjectFactory.java from xsd file. When try to create XML it is showing error. i'm using liferay  and java 1.8. Let me know any more information you need.

`ClassLoader classLoader=ObjectFactory.class.getClassLoader();

JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.package.JaxAddSystem",classLoader);`

Error:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: ClassCastException: attempting to cast jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_221/jre/lib/rt.jar!/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class to bundleresource://4202.fwk877311379:19/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class.  Please make sure that you are specifying the proper ClassLoader.      _ - with linked exception:_[javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: ClassCastException: attempting to cast jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_221/jre/lib/rt.jar!/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class to bundleresource://4202.fwk877311379:19/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class.  Please make sure that you are specifying the proper ClassLoader.    ] [Sanitized]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:202)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:129)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:307)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:478)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:435)
```

Comment: this is a typical osgi reference error .. the class is in separate classloaders at the same time ... and your are using both .. I would suggest : use the classes of the osgi runtime , by importing them in your manifest (probably through bnd)

Comment: I have made few changes, now com.sun.xml.bind.v2.contextFactory exception is gone. but something different issue comes up. ClassLoader classloader =ContextFactory.class.getClassLoader(); JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.Package.JaxAddSystem",classloader); Issue: "com.Package.JaxAddSystem" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index . How to resolve this issue, It would be great if you elaborate the upper answer @Andre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About your issue:

> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: ClassCastException: attempting to cast jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_221/jre/lib/rt.jar!/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class to bundleresource://4202.fwk877311379:19/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class.  Please make sure that you are specifying the proper ClassLoader.      _ - with linked exception:_[javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: ClassCastException: attempting to cast jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_221/jre/lib/rt.jar!/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class to bundleresource://4202.fwk877311379:19/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class.  Please make sure that you are specifying the proper ClassLoader.    ] [Sanitized]
>      at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:202)
>      at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:129)
>      at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:307)
>      at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:478)
>      at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:435)

It is caused because JAXBContext is being loaded from Liferay classloader (webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-api.jar) but there is other point that the JAXBContext is being loaded from OSGI module ( bundleresource://4202.fwk877311379:19/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class)

I ran into this issue in the past and I detected that root cause of this issue is a class named "com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory" from JAXB library.
That class is being loaded from Liferay classloader because **"com.sun.xml"** package is included in `module.framework.properties.org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation` portal.properties configuration. See: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/b825851dd2f8b617e3d129ff8815e31825a8cc92/portal-impl/src/portal.properties#L7759-L7786

In order to solve this issue, you can add `javax.xml.*` to `module.framework.properties.org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation` property in your portal-ext.properties.

So you have to copy default value of `module.framework.properties.org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation` to your portal-ext.properties and append `javax.xml.*` to it.

With this change, JAXB classes will be always loaded from Liferay classloader, avoiding all ClassCastException issues.